# csvsimple row counter processing

Tags: hyperref, csv, csvsimple

I am trying to list data from a csv file using `csvsimple` and to add automatic hyperlinks to related sections.

### Issue

When working with a file with a header (but using the `no head` option to define a different behaviour for the header), the row count is incremented by 1 which shifts the indexes accordingly.

This causes undefined references.

### Question

Is there a way to somehow use `(\thecsvrow - 1)` instead of the actual row number?

Do I absolutely have to manually modify my indexes to match the counter?

### MWE

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
name,type,value
var1,numeric,32+1
var2,string,"text"
var3,float,3.14-x
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\section{Variables}\label{sec:var}

\csvloop{
  file=data.csv,
  respect all,
  separator=comma,
  no head,
  column names={1=\variableName, 2=\variableType, 3=\variableValue},
  before reading={
    \begin{table}
      \centering
    \begin{tabular}{llr}
    \toprule
  },
  command={\csviffirstrow
    {\textbf{\variableName} & \textbf{\variableType} & \textbf{\variableValue}}
    {\hyperref[sec:var-\thecsvrow]{\variableName} & \variableType & \variableValue}
  },
  late after line=\\,
  late after first line=\\\midrule,
  late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
  after reading={
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{List of variables}
    \label{tab:variables}
    \end{table}
  }
}

\subsection{Variable 1}\label{sec:var-1}
\dots

\subsection{Variable 2}\label{sec:var-2}
\dots

\subsection{Variable 3}\label{sec:var-3}
\dots

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing with the `csvrow` counter seems to work.

I've subtracted 1 from the counter before the `\hyperref` and then restored to the original value adding 1 (otherwise it'd always have the value of 1):

```
\addtocounter{csvrow}{-1}\hyperref[sec:var-\thecsvrow]{\variableName}\addtocounter{csvrow}{1}
```

Please note that I removed the option `[draft]` from your `\documentclass` command, otherwise the links don't work, and, if you use Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, you have to enlarge the document to see the links working (at least at 60%, since the sub sections are empty).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
    name,type,value
    var1,numeric,32+1
    var2,string,"text"
    var3,float,3.14-x
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Variables}\label{sec:var}
    
    \csvloop{
        file=data.csv,
        respect all,
        separator=comma,
        no head,
        column names={1=\variableName, 2=\variableType, 3=\variableValue},
        before reading={
            \begin{table}
                \centering
                \begin{tabular}{llr}
                    \toprule
                },
                command={\csviffirstrow
                    {\textbf{\variableName} & \textbf{\variableType} & \textbf{\variableValue}}
                    {\addtocounter{csvrow}{-1}\hyperref[sec:var-\thecsvrow]{\variableName}\addtocounter{csvrow}{1} & \variableType & \variableValue}
                },
                late after line=\\,
                late after first line=\\\midrule,
                late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
                after reading={
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{List of variables}
                \label{tab:variables}
            \end{table}
        }
    }
    
    \subsection{Variable 1}\label{sec:var-1}
    \dots
    
    \subsection{Variable 2}\label{sec:var-2}
    \dots
    
    \subsection{Variable 3}\label{sec:var-3}
    \dots
    
\end{document}
```

Clicking on `var1` here:

[image]

You go to `Variable 1` subsection:

[image]

and so on.

Comment: Clever solution. Thank you for taking the time to explain and format your answer clearly.